# SQL JSON array sort

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, apache-spark-sql

record in DB:

```
id     info
0     [{"name":"a", "time":"2017-9-25 17:20:21"},{"name":"b", "time":"2017-9-25 23:23:41"},{"name":"c", "time":"2017-9-25 12:56:78"}]
```

my goal is to sort json array column `info` base on `time`, like:

```
id     info
0     [{"name":"c", "time":"2017-9-25 12:56:78"},{"name":"a", "time":"2017-9-25 17:20:21"},{"name":"b", "time":"2017-9-25 23:23:41"},]
```

I use sparkSQL, having no clue

Comment: is it possible to just write a program, query all the rows out, de-serialize it, reorder it in code, and update it row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I Suggest**

*Alternate Database Storage System*

I would not recommend storing data in this manner.  It simply makes your data less accessible and malleable as you are experiencing now. If you store your data like this:

```
id     name    time
0      a       2017-9-25 17:20:21
0      b       2017-9-25 23:23:41
0      c       2017-9-25 12:56:71
1      ...     ...
```

Then you can select the data in time order using the `ORDER BY` method at the end of a select query.  For example:

```
SELECT name, time FROM table_name where id=0 ORDER BY time asc;
```

If you have more columns in this table that you did not show, you may need a another table to efficiently store the information, but the performance benefits of foreign keys and joins between these types of tables would outweigh having all the data in one table as inconvenient JSON arrays.

Comment: if solution is that simple, I won't ask for it here,data structure is unchangeable

Comment: @no123ff showing little bit of courtesy would always be appreciated =)

Comment: @no123ff I will try to make a MySQL procedure to work around your preferred data structure.

Comment: @no123ff I recommend you read through some of the accepted database norms on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by converting the json array into a sql result set, extract the sorting column, and finally convert it back to a json array:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '[
    {"name":"a", "time":"2017-09-25 17:20:21"},
    {"name":"b", "time":"2017-09-25 23:23:41"},
    {"name":"c", "time":"2017-09-25 12:56:59"}
    ]';

WITH T AS (
    SELECT [Value] AS array_element
        , TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE(Value, 'strict $.time') AS DATETIME) AS sorting
    FROM OPENJSON(@json, 'strict $')
)
SELECT STRING_AGG(T.array_element, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sorting)
FROM T
```

Notice:

- I changed the sample data slightly, due to invalid months and seconds.
- The [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) function is only available from SQL 2017/Azure SQL Database. For older versions, use the classic "FOR XML PATH" method, which I will leave as an exercise to the reader.

If you want to apply it to a full sql table, use CROSS APPLY as follows:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '[
    {"name":"a", "time":"2017-09-25 17:20:21"},
    {"name":"b", "time":"2017-09-25 23:23:41"},
    {"name":"c", "time":"2017-9-25 12:56:59"}
    ]';

WITH dat AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,@json), (2,@json)) AS T(id, info)
)
, T AS (
    SELECT id, [Value] AS array_element
            , TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE(Value, 'strict $.time') AS DATETIME) AS sorting
    FROM dat
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(info, 'strict $')
)
SELECT id
    , STRING_AGG(T.array_element, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sorting) AS info
FROM T
GROUP BY id
```